# Java Native Function Returns value to a different caller object

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have one class which makes a native call to authenticate a user. At any given point of a time there can be 50-100 objects of this class trying to authenticate a user. The execution time for the native call function is in milliseconds but when it returns the result, the result gets mapped to a different object because of which the authentication fails.

e.g -

```
public class AS400Invoker {
    native String authenticateUser(String message, String channelNo);
    native String changePin(String message, String channelNo);
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AS400Invoker.class);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(PropertiesBean.readProperty("libraryname"));
    }
    public String userAuthetication(String ucid, String phoneCode, String pin, String channelNo){
        String toRet = null;
        try {
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] Inside user authentication function");
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] phone code received from IVR: "+phoneCode);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] channel number received from IVR: "+channelNo);
            UserAuthentication ua = new UserAuthentication();
            String formedMessage = ua.authenticateUser(ucid, phoneCode, pin);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] user authentication formed message length: "+formedMessage.length());
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] calling native function to authenticate user....");
            if(null != formedMessage)
                toRet = authenticateUser(formedMessage, channelNo);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] response received from native function: "+toRet);
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            logger.error("["+ucid+"] Runtime exception occured", e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("["+ucid+"] Generic exception occured", e);
        }
        return toRet;
    }
    public String pinChange(String ucid, String phoneCode, String pin, String cif, String channelNo){
        String toRet = null;
        try {
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] Inside pin change function");
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] phone code received from IVR: "+phoneCode);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] CIF received from IVR: "+cif);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] channel number received from IVR: "+channelNo);
            PinChange pc = new PinChange();
            String formedMessage = pc.changePin(ucid, phoneCode, pin, cif);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] pin change formed message length: "+formedMessage.length());
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] calling native function to change the pin....");
            if(null != formedMessage)
                toRet = changePin(formedMessage, channelNo);
            logger.info("["+ucid+"] response received from native function: "+toRet);
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            logger.error("["+ucid+"] Runtime exception occured", e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("["+ucid+"] Generic exception occured", e);
        }
        return toRet;
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, the result from the native call gets jumbled up. Can any one of you please throw some light on what might be going wrong in these calls? Below is the Log snippet for the same. In the below snippet the request is raised by the object whose UCID is 00001081951348702252 but the response gets mapped to a different UCID 00001080011348671171 and in reality, the response is for 00001081951348702252 UCID.

```
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,046 [http-7080-2] (UserAuthentication.java:11) - [00001081951348702252] Inside User Authentication
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,047 [http-7080-2] (UserAuthentication.java:21) - [00001081951348702252] Phone Code: 7447225
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,047 [http-7080-2] (UserAuthentication.java:23) - [00001081951348702252] Pin code received
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,048 [http-7080-2] (AS400Invoker.java:51) - [00001081951348702252] user authentication formed message length: 68
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,048 [http-7080-2] (AS400Invoker.java:52) - [00001081951348702252] calling native function to authenticate user....
INFO 2012-09-27 07:30:58,201 [http-7080-13] (AS400Invoker.java:55) - [00001080011348671171] response received from native function: 000OCBC08100C1C000000000008zF      621372010937239879230990239023    9D0001641412549001       01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      C              HHHHH CULTURE PVT. LTD     201206449R                         XYZ
```

Comment: It all depends on the code you didn't show us, for example `authenticateUser()` and `changePin()`. Are they using any static data?

Comment: Some of these responses which are getting mapped to wrong objects are quite old, say, 10-12 hours back

Comment: No, I am not using any static data as such

Comment: Its not allowing me to add the source code. Are you looking for the native function?

Comment: If you look back at what details you have given us. How do you think that anyone is going to be able to tell you what's wrong? There must be some more meat you can throw to us.

Comment: Hello Maba, can you please let me know what kind of additional information are you looking at?

Comment: Can you show us the native code for the native functions?

Comment: Hello Jakub, The native code is developed by another vendor and he informed me that there is no problem at their end, its returning the correct response but somehow it is getting mapped to the wrong object.

Comment: Where does the uicd variable come from?

Comment: The UCID variable comes from an IVR (Interactive Voice Response) application. The IVR call flow has a servlet which creates an object of AS400Invoker class and calls the userAuthentication() function passing the relevant parameters

Comment: UCID stands for Universal Call Identifier

Comment: So there is no way the ucid variable can change during userAuthetication? Please remember that String is a reference variable, so if you change the underlying string, all references are affected.

Comment: Yes, the UCID is passed by the IVR call flow. If you can take a look into the log snippet, it tells that the IVR application did pass the proper UCID but when the response came back from the native function, it got mapped to a different object. When this library is loaded in static block, there will be only instance of this library but there will be many requests, could that make any difference when the response comes back?

Comment: I suspect that the response is returned to the correct obejct, but whose ucid has already changed. It takes the native function some time to process a request, by which time the IVR can issue another call. It reuses the ucid variable, which will then change for the previous call as well.

Comment: Try adding a private unique attribute to AS400Invoker and log that alongside the ucid. Then you will see it is indeed a different object, or the same object with changed ucid.

Comment: Hello Jakub, the wrong UCID which it is printing in the log is at least 10 hours old and the response from the native function is coming in milliseconds. Can you please elaborate more on that private unique attribute? Is it something kind of integer variable??

Comment: ok, thanks a lot Jakub. I will try to add an integer variable

Comment: Could you print the **formedMessage** and **channelNo** before and after the native call?

Comment: @SumeetChakraborty Well can you show us the code for `UserAuthentication` and `PinChange` then. That is where the mapping seem to take place.